# Why Leetcode initializes a static variable in C to 0?

Tags: c

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHjVl.png) Sorry guys, why my output is wrong in this case?  How is possible that the correct answer is 2?
https://leetcode.com/problems/jump-game-ii/
i'm trying to solve the jump II problem. On Codeblocks, results are correct, on Leetcode no. I figured out that the site initializes the static variable min to 0,instead of the value i wrote,100. It's strange beacause in the other cases the site initializes correctly it. Here's the code.

```
int jump(int* nums, int numsSize){
    static int i=0;
    static int shots=0;
    static int min=100;

    if (i == numsSize - 1){
        if (shots < min){
            min = shots;
        }
        return min; 

    }      

    else if(nums[0] >= (numsSize-i)){
        i++;      
        shots++;  
        min=jump(&(nums[1]), numsSize);    //single jump in one shot
        i--;      
        shots--;  
        return min;
    }       

    else{  
        if(nums[0] != 0){
            i += nums[0];
            shots++;   
            min = jump(&(nums[nums[0]]), numsSize);//multiple jump in one shot 
            shots--;    
            i -= nums[0];
        }               
        i++;    
        shots++;
        min=jump(&(nums[1]), numsSize);  //single jump in one shot
        i--;    
        shots--;
        return min;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Please properly format your code!

Comment: "I figured out that the site initializes the static variable min to 0" -- How did you figure that out? Do you know that it is so or is it just a hunch?

Comment: Why do you use static variables in the first place? Leetcode probably throws several test cases at you. How do you reset `min` between cases? I think you should rework your algorithm. Static variables have their place, but here, the state could be a struct that you pass to the function instead.

Comment: I figured it out because I wrote a printf in the right place to know the value of min. How can i preserve the value of min through the different recoursive calls without using static variables and without changing the prototype of the function?

Comment: Do you really need to preserve it? You already return it from the function. Why not use that value?

Comment: Yes. How do i know the value of min if i make another call after i returned from the previous one? Can i change the prototype of the function on LeetCode?

Comment: While possible, it's not likely that the static variable isn't initialized, I'd be inclined to think that there is undefined behavior here which results in this value being changed. Is it really `0` the first time you enter the functions. But anyway, this approach is very hard to test and debug properly. It would be much better to make your functions stateless and pass state as parameters, instead of doing things like `i++; recursive_call(); i--;`.

Comment: No, you cannot change the prototype, because Leetcode is going to call that function with the test-case parameters. But you can write your own recursive function and call that function from `jump` . (You will probably need some kind of memoization in order to avoid the dreaded TLE.)

Comment: So, have I to create another function with an appropiate call?

Comment: On the first else you do `i++` and `i--` without using `i`

Comment: @Ôrel: `i` is static and may be used in the recursive call to `jump`. (Yes, the code is convoluted that way.)

Comment: Perhaps you should state what the actual intention of your code is and provide some input/output examples. This is unnecessarily convoluted, and likely doesn't need any recursion at all. Also, the usual way of doing recursion would be to decrement `numsSize` on each call, instead of introducing an additional variable, let alone making this variable static. Calls like `jump(&(nums[1]), numsSize);` don't give me confidence that you are reading withing the bounds of the array. Compare this to something `if (numsSize > 0) jump(nums + 1, numsSize - 1);` which would clearly state the intent.

Comment: I edited my post. Can you ask my question about that error? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `min` variable is marked `static`. That means it preserves its value between invocations of `jump`. I think you're using this because you want to modify it in recursive calls to `jump`, but a side-effect is that it's also preserved across test cases.

What's happening is that Codeblocks, each test case is being run separately (in a separate run of your program). So each time, `min` is statically initialized to 100. On Leetcode, the test cases are being run one after the other in a loop. That means, if one test run returns 0, then `min` is not re-initialized back to 100 for subsequent test runs. Of course, I don't know this for sure, but it seems very likely, and this mis-use of `static` is definitely a fault in your code that will cause bugs if the function is used twice.

You probably have the same problems with `i` and `shots`.

If you really need state that's needed down a recursion tree, it's better to pass it down explicitly. If you need to update it too (which you do here), then use a pointer argument.

Perhaps something like this:

```
typedef struct jump_state_s {
    int min;
    int i;
    int shots;
} jump_state_s;

int jump1(int* nums, int numsSize, jump_state_s *js) {
    if (js->i == numsSize - 1){
        if (js->shots < js->min){
            js->min = js->shots;
        }
        return js->min; 
    }      
    ... rest of code
}

int jump(int *nums, int numsSize) {
    jump_state_s js = {100, 0, 0};
    return jump1(nums, numsSize, &js);
}
```

Note that this is not the best way of programming the solution to this problem, and will result in exponential time in the worst case. The best solution looks like an iterative dynamic-programming solution, using an array of "best" values for each square.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The strange thing is that i and shoots are fine. I've tried different cases and it's ok. In the base case of Leetcode, min is 100. Then, when i submit, it cause me error. And min is 0. I understand that i've to try another way. Thanks for the support.

Comment: I edited my post. Can you ask my question about that error? Thanks!